# Strange behaviour of app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php file

Tags: magento-1.9, helper, core, magento-core

I have Magento 1.9.3.1 CE installed and unaltered in my Uwamp localhost.

I was just casually testing some functions from the app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php file, by calling those functions in my root script as below:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Varien_Profiler::enable();
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

echo Mage::helper('core')->__('any text to be printed');
echo Mage::helper('core')->now();
```

But when I called the `now` method of the same `functions.php` file, I got the below error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Helper_Data::now() in C:\UwAmp\www\[magento-root]\test.php on line 11
```

I was astonished, confused and annoyed to find that even though `functions.php` actually contains the function `now`, it doesn't allow it to be called from any other file(or root script as in my case).

Please check [here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php#L119) to ascertain that `now` function actually exists in `functions.php` file.

What on the earth could be possible cause for this weird scenario?

Answer (score 1):

now() isn't actually part of the 'core' helper. It is a method inside of the `app/code/local/Mage/Core/functions.php` file that gets included in `app/Mage.php` like this:

```
include_once "Mage/Core/functions.php";
```

The correct way to call this would be:

```
echo now();
```

You don't need the `Mage::helper('core')` part since it's not actually part of the core helper and isn't even in a class at all.

You can verify this by adding your own method to `Mage/Core/functions.php` as a test.

I added:

```
function sean() {
    return 'test';
}
```

to the bottom of functions.php. I was then able to access it like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

echo sean();
```

I ran the test file above and the result was `test`